# How do I print filled textboxes only and the labels near them?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write code that can print only filled text boxes in the form and then print the label near them. 
I searched and thought the code below is the end result I could reach.
I am using vb.net 2008

```
    Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    '===============================================================================================
    Dim name As String
    Dim cc As Integer
    Dim f As New Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Underline)
    Dim b As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
    Dim c As Integer = 60

    'search for filled textboxes

    For Each ctrl In Me.TabControl1.TabPages(0).Controls

        If (TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox) Then

            If CType(ctrl, TextBox).Text.Length > 0 Then
                e.Graphics.DrawString(CType(ctrl, TextBox).Text, f, b, 30, c)
                c = c + 30

                If c > 60 Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If

    Next
    '======================================================
    'to know if previuos for loop actualy find any
    If c > 60 Then
        ' to be print over textboxes if are there  
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Label6.Text, f, b, 16, 30)

    End If
    '======================================================
    ' this one to find out the name of the control wich found filled 
    For Each ctrl In Me.TabControl1.TabPages(0).Controls

        If (TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox) Then

            If CType(ctrl, TextBox).Text.Length > 0 Then
                name = ctrl.Name
                e.Graphics.DrawString(name, f, b, 0, c)

            End If
        End If
        Exit For
    Next
    'and this step to print the label with its textbox 
    If name = "TextBox2" Then
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Label1.Text, f, b, 0, c)

    ElseIf name = "TextBox3" Then
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Label2.Text, f, b, 0, c)

    ElseIf name = "textbox4" Then
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Label3.Text, f, b, 0, c)
    ElseIf name = "textbox5" Then

        e.Graphics.DrawString(Label4.Text, f, b, 0, c)
    End If


End Sub
```

So I don't know why I went so far away from the solution, maybe I need a little help from you guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first. Programming is understanding patterns.

So create a pattern first if you want to solve your problem.

The pattern required in your case is the naming strategy.

Just name the label and textbox properly.
eg.

```
lblFirstName txtFirstName 
lblLastName txtLastName
```

If you do so following will be the change in code. You don't need a extra loop for Labels.

```
    Dim ControlStack As New Stack(Of TextBox)

     For Each ctrl In Me.TabControl1.TabPages(0).Controls 'Modified to handle issue of taborder'
        If (TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox) Then
            ControlStack.Push(ctrl)
        End If
     Next

     For Each ctrl In ControlStack
        If (TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox) Then

            If CType(ctrl, TextBox).Text.Length > 0 Then
                name = ctrl.Name
                dim labelName as string 
                labelName ="lbl" & mid(name ,4)
                dim labelControl as Label 
                Dim controlsFound() As Control
                controlsFound = Controls.Find(labelName,True)
                If controlsFound.Length > 0 Then
                    labelControl = controlsFound(0)
                End If
                e.Graphics.DrawString(labelControl.Text , f, b, 0, c)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(ctrl.Text, f, b, 250, c)
            End If
        End If
        Exit For
    Next
```

Please let me know if you understand the same. As I have just given hint code not complete code.

Comment: that is briliant sachin i just.  cuold'nt fix the problem in     " dim labelControl as Label =Controls.Find(labelName,True) "line         its say "Value of type '1-dimensional array of System.Windows.Forms.Control' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'"  other than that i think it's fine

Comment: Just updated the code. Actully find returns an array. So you have to take just the 0th element from the same. Try it now.

Comment: ITS WORKS GREAT THANKS ALOT SACHIN YOU JUST GET ME OUT OF DEEP PROBLEM

Comment: I STILL HAVE THIS LITTLE TINY THING I CHANGED THE TABORDER OF THE TEXTBOXES INVERSELY TO MAKE IT ORDERED IN PRINTOUT BECAUSE THE LOOP BEGINS FROMM THE LAST ONE AND COME OVER SO THE TABKEY WILL'NT WORK IT WILL DO IT INVERSELY SO IS THERE IS ANY WAY TO KEEP TABKEY WORKIG ?

Comment: Done buddy. I have added the code above to push the controls in stack. Then used the stack. So the tab order is not disturbed.